# Options for getting into passcode-locked iPad 2 / iOS 5.1.1 (JB'd)?

Tags: ipad, jailbreak, password, security

I have an iPad 2 running iOS 5.1.1 and it is jailbroken (though as far as I know, not running SSH). A few hours ago I set a new 4-digit device passcode which I subsequently forgot. I've tried a few times now and it blocked me out for a full hour twice now, I suspect if I try again it will completely block the device.

I last made an iTunes backup and synchronisation about 3-4 months ago on a laptop that I still have, but is currently unusable (the HDD is in another country, I won't be able to use that laptop for at least 2 more weeks).

I have other computers with iTunes, when I connect my iPad to this other machines I get a message telling me that I have to unlock it first before iTunes will connect to it, which means that I cannot browse the filesystem using iExplorer or iFunBox (then I would be able to delete the keychain file and get in that way... I hope). **I think that if I connect my iPad to my original laptop (2 weeks away) that I'll be able to get-in without needing the passcode? Is this true?**

I found out about the Gecko iPhone Toolkit, however that only works up to iPhone 4 (A4) whereas the iPad 2 is an A5-powered device. I also couldn't find any download links, oddly enough.

[I read about a Ramdisk that I could boot from in Recovery Mode that has an SSH server](http://modmyi.com/forums/general/758778-emergency-ssh-access-using-pwnd-dfu-mode-ramdisk.html), but the steps looked too complicated and the forum posts don't mention the iPad 2 and iOS 5 which made me wonder if it would work or not, I didn't want to risk it.

I see that commercial forensics tools like [Elcomsoft's iOS Toolkit](http://www.elcomsoft.com/eift.html) and [Cellebrite UFED](http://www.cellebrite.com/mobile-forensic-products/ufed-applications/ufed-physical-analyzer.html) claim to be able to get into my device, **but if they can do it how come the jailbreakers can't?**

Coincidentally, I contacted a local data recovery company and they left me a voicemail just now saying that they wouldn't be able to recover data from an iPad 2, only a first-generation iPad, which is a bummer - but I don't know what tool they use.

I'll try contacting other data recovery companies in the meanwhile, but is my situation really helpless?

### Update:

I tried another passcode attempt and that caused my iPad to be disabled. Ho-hum. I returned home today and plugged my iPad into my laptop and while iTunes did not offer to remove the passcode I was able to access the raw filesystem using iFunBox, which I could not do when my iPad was connected to any of my other computers.

I deleted the `keychain-2.db` and `com.apple.springboard.plist` files and rebooted my device, however the passcode prompt still persists.

I'm not too bothered about the passcode on the device preventing me from logging-in because iFunBox gives me the raw filesystema access so I can grab the files and data I need (such as my iMessages database) and wipe the device at a later date if I can't get the passcode back.

Still, if anyone knows why deleting `keychain-2.db` didn't work, please let me know.

Comment: Ramdisks require a bootrom exploit, which doesn't exist (as of this writing) for A5 devices.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to fix this is to erase and restore the device.

See http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1212 for more details and options.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get into your iPad without losing any data. 
Open iTunes on your computer. Disable your iPad and press and hold the lock button until slide to power off appears. Click Cancel. iPad is disabled should disapear. Plug into iTunes. Back up and then restore. Restore from the backup you made. TADA! No passcode. Wait until it finishes its sync with iTunes before disconecting. Redownload the stuff from other computers that you put on. You will have to re-jailbreak your iPad.

Comment: I've got up to the stage of cancelling and plugging in iTunes, however the iPad2 does not appear under Devices, and backup is greyed out. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope... the "Disabled" does NOT disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Computers that have been synced with iTunes do not need to enter a password the next time they connect to the iPad. But unfortunately, due to technical limitations of iOS devices, there is currently no iOS unlocking tool that can unlock iPad without deleting data. Whether you use dr.fone, FoneCope or any other tool. If you don't have iCloud backups or other available backups, this can be a disaster. If you can, you'd better get your original computer as soon as possible. Otherwise you can only recover the [forgotten iPad 2 4-digit passcode](https://www.fonecope.com/forgot-ipad-passcode.html) by sacrificing the data.